# Узнать имя компьютера и его IP по названию сайта

Tags: c#, .net

Сейчас я это делаю таким образом:

```
var entryPoint = Dns.GetHostEntry(tmp);
ip = entryPoint.AddressList.First();
name = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip).HostName;
```

Как видите, сначала я обращаюсь по имени сайта что бы получить IP, а потом по IP, что бы получить имя машины.

Если попытаться получить HostName из первого entryPoint, то там будет название сайта, что мне не нужно...

Можно ли как-нибудь иначе получить нужную мне информацию?

Мой способ выглядит каким-то костыльным.

Comment: *там будет название сайта, что мне не нужно...* А что нужно? *получить имя машины* У машины много разных имён... и не все они доступны через DNS.

Comment: @Akina, название самого сервера на котором хостится данный сайт.

Comment: Тогда получайте все IP-адреса данного URL и все имена всех полученных IP. И, кстати, URL сайта - это правильный, хоть и не единственный, вариант - на этом же IP может быть немеряное количество сайтов, ещё большой вопрос, что считать за "базовое" имя узла.

Comment: @Akina, а не дадите мне наводку на метод или класс? Dns.GetHostEntry мне вернул для этого сайта все в единственном экземпляре.

Comment: Ну, значит, у этого сервера эксклюзивный белый адрес и единственное DNS-имя. Нормальное состояние. Можно для подстраховки выгрузить обратную зону для этого адреса - там должна быть единственная PTR-запись.

Comment: @Akina, однако,  можно ли получить нужную мне информацию(название ПК) за одно обращение к EntryPoint? Сейчас я его могу получить при повторном запрос, но не по имени сайта, а по IP.

Comment: Сначала Вы обращаетесь к прямой зоне и получаете адрес. Потом к обратной, и получаете имя. Одним запросом и туда, и сюда обратиться нельзя.

Comment: О каком имени компьютера вы говорите? Привожу наглядную иллюстрацию: один из моих серверов является виртуальной машиной msk-web-126.carvin-nt с тремя сетевыми картами (две в интернет торчат, одна во внутреннюю сеть конторы) и на нём находится сайт скажем www.cinderella.ru на IP = 5.6.7.8 и moscquite.ru на IP = 5.6.7.9 -- и ещё есть IP = 10.0.0.15 на второй сетевой карте. Что вы хотите получить по имени сайта www.cinerella.ru?